# Transfer File via Bluetooth with Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

i want to code an application which enable file sharing via Bluetooth with android, but i can't find samples which i can base on.  Please can someone give me links to some samples.

Comment: See here: http://igtfy.com/?q=android+bluetooth+code+examples+file+sharing

Comment: I am tired of googling, but i can't find a working sample for .

Answer (score 0):

There is really a lot of info all over the place about this.

A good starting point is always the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) it also has examples too!

As was mentioned a quick google search should have given you a lot of examples programs [but here is one anyways.](http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/)